# Can a smartphone's PIN or password be brute-forced in an offline attack?

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, smartphone

I know of exhaustive offline dictionary and brute-force attacks against any given online account, but can the same method be applied against phones, either Android/iPhones? Or would any such attack be actually thwarted thanks to the default lock-out settings that are available on phones these days?
Thank you

Comment: "off-line" brute-forcing does not mean to have the device disconnect from the network . It  means to not interact with the device through the official interface at all but instead somehow extract relevant information from the device and then try to detect the PIN or similar only using these information. Thus, default lock-out settings don't matter for this kind of attack at all. It is more relevant if one can extract the necessary information from the locked device or some backup in the first place and then if a brute-force attack using these information is fast enough.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If you could extra links for reference, your comment could make a nice answer.

Comment: Talking about offline attacks, you should consider not only PIN bruteforce but also disk (internal storage) encryption.

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich so essentially you're saying that it CAN be done, and pretty easily, right? In other words, the automatic lockout (after, say, 10 unsuccessful guesses) doesn't really help if an attacker uses some sort of brute-forcing software against the phone and determines the right PIN/password to unlock the screen?

Comment: Not pretty easy, but undoubtly can be done. That security meassure is implemented in the OS, not in the SIM, so a modded android without that lock-out setting would deffinitevely make it. Do note that if it were in a chip in the phone, custom hardware could make it possible (harder, but possible).

Comment: @nnad: I'm not saying that it can be easily done. I'm saying that you need to *"extract the necessary information from the locked device or some backup in the first place"*  and then find a way to brute-force this which *"is fast enough"*. I'm not saying that any of these requirements is easy or even feasible at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich if physical acces to the smartphone is given, cloning the SIM would be the best way to go. You could bruteforce the clonned SIM

Comment: @bradbury9: the PIN/password to the device is not on the SIM.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich cell network auth? Thanks for the correction.